# Word2Vec error when loading in GoogleNews data

Tags: python, word2vec

I am following a tutorial here: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568

I am at the part "Word2vec and Logistic Regression". I have downloaded the "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz" file and I am tyring to apply it to my own text data. However when I get to the following code:

```
%%time
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

wv = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("/data/users/USERS/File_path/classifier/GoogleNews_Embedding/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)
wv.init_sims(replace=True)
```

I run into the following error:

```
/data/users/msmith/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py:398: UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. See the migration notes for details: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function
  'See the migration notes for details: %s' % _MIGRATION_NOTES_URL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
   1492         return _load_word2vec_format(
   1493             cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding, unicode_errors=unicode_errors,
-> 1494             limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
   1495 
   1496     def get_keras_embedding(self, train_embeddings=False):

~/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
    383                 with utils.ignore_deprecation_warning():
    384                     # TODO use frombuffer or something similar
--> 385                     weights = fromstring(fin.read(binary_len), dtype=REAL).astype(datatype)
    386                 add_word(word, weights)
    387         else:

/usr/lib64/python3.6/gzip.py in read(self, size)
    274             import errno
    275             raise OSError(errno.EBADF, "read() on write-only GzipFile object")
--> 276         return self._buffer.read(size)
    277 
    278     def read1(self, size=-1):

/usr/lib64/python3.6/_compression.py in readinto(self, b)
     66     def readinto(self, b):
     67         with memoryview(b) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
---> 68             data = self.read(len(byte_view))
     69             byte_view[:len(data)] = data
     70         return len(data)

/usr/lib64/python3.6/gzip.py in read(self, size)
    480                 break
    481             if buf == b"":
--> 482                 raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
    483                                "end-of-stream marker was reached")
    484 

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Any idea whats gone wrong/ how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you verify that file you downloaded is not damaged?

Comment: I will re-download it and get back to you! Do you know how to download the file directly from Python? In R we have the `docwnload.file()` function. I am trying to get this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit so i am downloading it to my desktop and then uploading it to the server so it might get corrupt during this process.

Comment: it's not a direct link so you need to do some tricks. you can use youtube-dl package.
from the command line it would look like 
`youtube-dl https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit`